# Image paste into contenteditable div working for a wrong reason in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, copy-paste

In my code, I am generating a thumbnail of the image being drag-dropped or copy-pasted. Drag and drop is not a problem but with copy-paste, I can see an error in Safari (snapshot below) *but still the thumbnail is generated!*

**Error:**
[image]

**Relevant snippet of my code:**

```js
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('paste', function(event){
  console.log("pasted!", event);
  this.style.background='green';

  // get pasted data; Source: http://codingmiles.com/pasting-image-contenteditable-div/
  var pastedData = event.clipboardData.items[0];

  console.log("pastedData",pastedData);

  // If the clipboard data is of type image, read the data
  if(pastedData.type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
    console.log('calling thumbnail function'); // does not show up in the console! o.O
    composeThumbnail(pastedData.getAsFile()); // this still works!
  }
});

function composeThumbnail(file) { // source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

  if (!/^image\//.test(file.type)) { // if not an image; 0 since we take only 1 image, if multiple dragged at once, consider only the first one in the array
    console.log('ERROR: Not an image file.');
    return false;
  }

  // compose an <img> for the thumbnail
  var thumbnailImage = document.createElement("img");
  thumbnailImage.file = file;
  document.getElementById('target').appendChild(thumbnailImage);

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (function(thumbnailImage) {
    // this image is part of the data, so send typing notification to the agent
    return function(event) {
      thumbnailImage.src = event.target.result;
    };
  })(thumbnailImage);

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

```css
#target{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 15px;
}

#target img{
  height: 25%;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#target *{
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="target" contenteditable="true"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

As mentioned in the comments, I have used [this resource](https://web.archive.org/web/20161206052921/http://codingmiles.com:80/pasting-image-contenteditable-div/) for the paste event handler.

My Safari version is 9.1 and I am on Mac OS X El Capitan.

Why is the thumbnail still being generated? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Safari does NOT support pasting images into contenteditable DIV.
The last time I checked with Safari v9.1.1, it still isn't supported.

You can take a look at the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/layerssss/paste.js/issues/21), it says so.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late, but instead of

```
{
 var pastedData = event.clipboardData.items[0];
}
```

try

```
{
 var pastedData = event.clipboardData.files[0];
 .
 .
 .
 composeThumbnail(pastedData)
}
```

event.clipboardData.items gives a list of DataTransferItemList which is not supported by Safari